# window.focus() not working after geolocation callback

Tags: javascript

I experience a weird situation. This script works in all browser (firefox ,safari, chrome desktop). except chrome mobile (keyboard will popup, but field not gets focused and if we start typing there is nothing on the field). What this script do is: after processing geolocation it will focus on input field.

```
function success(pos) {

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("input-field-1").focus();   //after finish focus to input field
  }, 0);

}
if (window.confirm('allow us to access location?')) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
}
```

Is it a chrome mobile bug or do i miss something?